# Laravel - Dynamic config file

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Hello dear community!

**SITUATION**

I'm restructuring a tenant-based application.

Currently there exist 3 .env files (local, development, production) for each tenant and i load the correct .env file through a logic of IF's in bootstrap/app.php depending on the SERVER_NAME from the request.

**TASK/IDEA**

Now i wan't to shift away from overloading .env files, especially since the 'configs' aren't differenciating from (e.g.) *.env-local* to *.env-development*.

So; a config-file where i store those settings would be the most logic idea

**config/tenant.php**

```
<?php

$tenantArr= [
    1 => [
        "id"              => 1,
        "name"            => "Config 1",
        "user_login"      => "ldap",
        "role_management" => "abo",
    ],
    2 => [
        "id"              => 2,
        "name"            => "Config 2",
        "user_login"      => "db",
        "role_management" => "abo",
    ],
    3 => [
        "id"              => 3,
        "name"            => "db 3",
        "user_login"      => "ldap",
        "role_management" => "abo",
    ]
];


return $tenantArr[ $tenant_id] ?? die("error; no key found");
```

**GOAL**

The goal is that i can load a config universally via (e.g.) **config('tenant.name')**.

(Later-on this of course get's more split up, perhaps with an Facade across the project to access further specifics of each tenant.)

**QUESTIONS**

Where could i implement the logic to get **$tenant_id**  in the last line?

Is there a way to pass the variable from bootstrap/app.php into the config-array?

Or should i simply insert my IF-logic at the start of the config-file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I won't say I recommend any of these approaches... but I will say `configs` can be set on the fly. This would allow you to set a new config (that is not set in any config files) from your `app.php` based on the tenant ID. Something like `Config::set('current_tenant', Config::get('tenant')[$tenant_id])`. Then your app would always access the config as if there were only one tenant.

Comment: Full disclosure - our company used the approach I described, so I know it works well, but we have removed it. "Magic" configs like that are hard to trace and understand long-term since they're set in a file (`bootstrap/app`) that most devs never need to open.

Comment: @BrianThompson thanks for your input! Care to give an example as how you would approach this? I sadly have to know what sort of tenant quite searly  in the application.

Perhaps make a ServiceProvider that sets the needed config via the Config-facade?

Comment: It's really hard to give that kind of advice because I would imagine the "best" way depends heavily on the application and usage. One approach I've used was to create something like a `Tenant` class that really is just a proxy to `Config` but makes it clear to devs that you're interacting with a custom structure, whereas a dev seeing `config('current_tenant')` would naturally assume there is a corresponding file in the `config` folder. In short, try to make it clear to yourself and any other developer how the values are getting set, and allow them to find out how without too much digging.

Comment: @BrianThompson
A `Tenant` class would be my second to-do anyway. Perhaps i'll just flatten out the logic as to what config to load in the `__construct` of the Model/Facade.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Little late to the party on this one.
None of these approaches are good in my book. Since I've done this several times here is my advise.
The best way in my eyes is doing a middleware attached to your routing. From there you can tell the tenant by either a subdomain or the first segment in your URL. Then store all that tenant info in the database with connection info to the separate tenant database. Once you know that connection info you can set a dynamic 2nd database connection.  Now you have separation of tenants but still using the main Laravel base framework at the same time. Keep your tenant models away from your framework models or you will have a nightmare on your hands.
Particularly important also is to always keep tenant code in their own namespaces. For instance on my latest enterprise multi-tenant that I've been working on for 5+ years:

```
app\Models\Main - this is the framework directory for models 
app\Models\Tenant\Foo - this is the Foo tenant directory for models
app\Models\Tenant\Bar - this is the Bar tenant directory for models
```

Then continue to do this for all tenants in controllers, public files, views and then have a separate route file for each tenant.
If you want to use a class between all tenants like a common menu system or something learn about using Traits. You can then share between all tenants and not have to have the same class 27 times in 27 different places.
Lots of info here and lots to think about. Giving you a shove in the right direction.  Also, dealing with a config file is a nightmare to change. Read about the order Laravel loads things up and then caches them.  You'd have to do a cache bust on almost every load and that's a huge performance hit.